# What is the referent for this them?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> "Charlie's in Romania studying dragons, and Bill's in Africa doing
>   something for Gringotts[bank]," said Ron. "Did you hear about
>   Gringotts? It's been all over the Daily Prophet, but I don't suppose
>   you get that with the Muggles - someone tried to rob a high security
>   vault." 
>   Harry stared. 
>   "Really? What happened to
>   **them**?" 
>   "Nothing, that's why it's such big news. They haven't been caught…”
>  (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Does ‘them’ indicate those who tried to rob the bank by the proximity rule, 
or those who are working for Gringotts? – ‘happened to’ is confusing me to tell which is right.

Comment: Yes, "them" refers to the muggles who tried to rob the vault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bill's comment is correct and incorrect.  Yes, *them* refers to the attempted bank robber (the 'someone' who tried to rob a high security vault).  It is being used as a non-specific plural as the thief's gender is unknown.

However, it was a wizard - not muggles - who had attempted the [theft](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gringotts_Wizarding_Bank).